# How to find total of all the estimates in query in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True)
    estimate = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, decimal_places=1, max_digits=4)
```

I want to find the  total of all estimates for all tickets that are assigned to a particular person.

I am trying to do:

```
for i in Person.objects.all():
    Ticket.objects.filter(assigned_to=i)
```

and use `Sum()` to add `estimate()` for each model.

But I am getting no data with the first query. I am sure I have datas. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this entirely in the db with an aggregate.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
people_with_estimates = Person.objects.all().annotate(
    estimate_total=Sum('ticket__estimate'))
```

Now each Person has an `estimate_total` attribute containing the sum of all their ticket estimates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the person try this:

```
estimate_total = Decimal(0)
ticket_list = Ticket.objects.filter(assigned_to = person.id)
for i in range(len(ticket_list)):
    estimate_total += ticket_list[i].estimate
```